# pgfplot: 2D with line color depending on another value

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to create a 2 dimensional plot with several lines.

One of the lines depends on additional values in third dimension. Now i'd like to make the line color of this "3d-line" depending on the third value.
So its about making a 2d plot from 3d data.

The color of third line (x3, y3) should be like a scatter plot. The color scheme used schould depend on the values of z3 though.

Since I have to make several of these plots it would be good if it could be as much "fully automated".

Would be great to get some help!

Thanks in advance!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[final]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}{x_y_z_values.txt}
x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 z3
1 1 1 2 1 3 3
2 2 2 3 2 4 9
3 3 3 4 3 5 27
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\pgfplotsset{width=\textwidth}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[]                
                table [col sep=space,x expr=\thisrow{x1},y expr=\thisrow{y1}]
                        {x_y_z_values.txt};
            \addplot[]                  
                table [col sep=space,x expr=\thisrow{x2},y expr=\thisrow{y2}]
                            {x_y_z_values.txt};
            \addplot[]
                table [col sep=space,x expr=\thisrow{x3},y expr=\thisrow{y3}]
                            {x_y_z_values.txt};\addlegendentry{3-d-line}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the plot will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

[image]

This can be achieved by using the `point meta` key which is explained in the pgfplots manual in more detail (Sec. 4.8.2).

```
\documentclass[final]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{filecontents*}{x_y_z_values.txt}
x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3 z3
1 1 1 2 1 3 3
2 2 2 3 2 4 9
3 3 3 4 3 5 27
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\pgfplotsset{width=\textwidth}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[colorbar]
            \addplot[mesh,point meta=explicit]                
                table [col sep=space,x expr=\thisrow{x1},y expr=\thisrow{y1},point meta=\thisrow{z3}]
                        {x_y_z_values.txt};
            \addplot[]                  
                table [col sep=space,x expr=\thisrow{x2},y expr=\thisrow{y2}]
                            {x_y_z_values.txt};
            \addplot[]
                table [col sep=space,x expr=\thisrow{x3},y expr=\thisrow{y3}]
                            {x_y_z_values.txt};\addlegendentry{3-d-line}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```